Up to what order have finite groups been classified?
All finite simple groups have been classified, and the classification of finite groups is thought to be wild. So, up to what order have finite groups been classified? Wikipedia tells us that it is known up to 2000, but presumably this is understood for far higher orders.

Even classifying extensions of a finite simple group by a finite elementary abelian $p$-group involves representation theory of groups of wild representation type, so is certainly a wild problem. The first order for which it is not known how many isomorphism types there are is $2048$. There are at least $1774274116992170$, and the first three digits are probably correct. What it means to classify these groups once you know how many there are, is unclear.

Indeed, as Dave Benson says, it's tricky to make precise the notion of "classification." Generally we might accept that "X structures are classified" if there is a computer program that in finite time can output a representative of each X isomorphism class. But of course, there is a dumb brute force algorithm that will output the multiplication tables for all groups (without repeats!) of order up to (say) a million. So are all groups of order up to a million "known" or "classified"?

I guess the only doubtful case less than $2048$ is order $1024$, where the number of isomorphism classes  is known but the groups have not been explicitly listed and stored in a computer. But I believe they could be listed in the unlikely event that the survival of the human race depended on doing so.

When there is a large number of groups, the definition of "classify" is questionable. Knowing the exact number of groups of order 2048 is not everything. Knowing a full list of such groups is not everything, since given two lists one needs to be able to know have they match.

I'm not sure whether it's even remotely useful to have a list of the 49487367289 isomorphism classes of groups of order 1024. What would you do with such a list? But if you think finite two-groups are bad in this sense, the situation for semigroups is much worse: the number of isomorphism/anti-isomorphism classes of semigroups of order 8 is already 1843120128. Mind you, the survival of the human race seems to depend on some much stupider things, now you come to mention it.

The interest in this question lies in its ambiguity! If the question is "what is the smallest $n$ such that we cannot easily  identify the position in the standard lists of a group isomorphic to a group $G$ given as a permutation group?", then I think the answer might be 512.
